# How to resize curses pad?

Tags: python, ncurses, curses

How can I resize curses pad, created with `newpad`? There is `window.resize` function and although window is similar object as pad, nothing explicitly says I can use this function to resize pad.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can call "resize()" on a pad object.  It is another type of "window" object in the Python curses model.  The thing about Python's "pad" objects is that their `.refresh()` method is rather non-intuitive (and poorly documented).  I can get it working, but I still find the six argument tuple that it requires to be baffling.